# how to convert the datatype of a varible while reading in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset like below and i am unable to know what are the tonumbers and what are the from numbers .I want to view them in a phone number format .please help me at this point

data

```
    MessageID     ToNumber       FromNumber
0   38114253    9.192232e+11    9.198451e+11
1   38114266    9.192232e+11    9.184230e+11
2   38114272    9.192232e+11    9.173537e+11
3   38114277    9.192232e+11    9.184949e+11
4   38114287    9.192232e+11    9.184229e+11
```

And expected output is like below and i am not sure that the end of the tonumber or from number is 12345. but i need it in the below format.

Expected output:

data

```
    MessageID     ToNumber       FromNumber
0   38114253    919223212345    919845112345
1   38114266    919223212345    918423012345
2   38114272    919223212345    917353712345
3   38114277    919223212345    918494912345
4   38114287    919223212345    918422912345
```

And this is just a sample data, I have 3 Million records like this and the datatype of tonumber variable is pandas.core.series.series.

please help me how to do this...

Comment: What are you using to load and store this data? Are these pandas dfs?

Comment: "Lahk" is Indian for 100,000. I don't recommend using it in English, it's not a common term.

Comment: modata = pd.read_csv("/home/path/MO.txt", sep='|', error_bad_lines=False)  .this is how i am reading the data

Comment: Open it in notepad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c= 9.192232e+11
d=int(c)
```

this will convert the value 9.192232e+11 as 919223200000L

If its ok to convert number as a string then you can make 919223200000L as 919223200000 by doing

```
number = str(d)
```

hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your field is not wide enough to fit the full reresentation of your number. If you can somehow make your ToNumber and FromNumber fields a little wider then the numbers full representation should be shown, which is a bit like in excel when the column is not wide enough it displays a load of #'s (However I am not certain as I can not use Pandas very well).

Comment: Sorry this won't work.please observe the data that it is in decimals